# Bevel gear friction and inertia calculation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, friction, power-transmission

I want to calculate the friction and inertia between 2 bevel gears with straight teeth.
I know how to calculate those parameters between regular gears with straight teeth.
Is there any difference for bevel gears?

Thanks,